# Variables that are needed for Bluetooth Connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

Currently, I'm trying to figure out how to stay connected with a device via Bluetooth throughout Activities. I have a few variables that I initialize to get the connection going.

My previous activity flow is Main Page > User input Text page > Bluetooth Connection(SENDING INFO).

So in this way, every time I go back to the User Input Text Page, the Bluetooth connection will be reset because when I go the next page, it'll rerun all the receivers and stuffs.

Now I'm moving the Bluetooth Connection forward. Meaning now it is Main Page > Bluetooth Connection > User Input Text Page(SEND).

But after I connect on my Bluetooth Connection page, I'm not sure what variables I should bring over/save inside `SharedPreferences`, so that the Bluetooth connection stays and I can send right away.

```
//This method runs when I click a device on my ListView.
    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect

                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                System.out.println("Bluetooth Adapter2 = "
                        + bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery());
                SiriListItem item = delist.get(arg2);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // When device being clicked
                count++;
                click = 1;
                // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the
                // View
                String info = item.message;
                String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
                BlueToothAddress = address;
                if (click == 1) {
                    clientThread ct = new clientThread();
                    ct.start();

                }
            };
        };

//This is the clientThread if click == 1, it'll start this.
private class clientThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {

            try {
                //
                bdDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BlueToothAddress);
                socket = bdDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
                        .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                Message msg2 = new Message();
                msg2.obj = "Please wait, connecting to server: "
                        + BlueToothAddress;
                msg2.what = 0;
                LinkDetectedHandler.sendMessage(msg2);
                socket.connect();
                Log.i("tag", "This is the pairing section");

                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "Device connected. Sending message is allowed.";
                msg.what = 0;
                LinkDetectedHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                readThread = new readThread();
                readThread.start();
                click++;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "Error! Can't connect to device. Please try again.";
                msg.what = 0;
                LinkDetectedHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                click--;

            }
        }
    };

public class readThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            InputStream mmInStream = null;
            String tmp = null;
            try {
                mmInStream = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // read the data from the inputStream
                    if ((bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
                            tmp = "" + buffer[i];
                            String st = new String(tmp);
                            tmp = null;
                            Message msg = new Message();
                            msg.obj = st;
                            msg.what = 1;

                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        mmInStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

//On Click it'll send the message stored in the editText.
buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(bluetoothtest.this,
                            "Please connect to a device first.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // Need API=14
                else if (!socket.isConnected()) {
                    Toast.makeText(bluetoothtest.this,
                            "Connecting! Please wait.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    try {
                        sendMessageHandle(contentRow1.getText().toString(),
                                contentRow2.getText().toString(), contentRow3
                                        .getText().toString(), contentRow4
                                        .getText().toString());
                        // sendMessageHandle(contentRow2.getText().toString());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

So the main thing is. What method should I have in my User Input Text Page? Must I have all this method in my User Input Text Page or can I just bring over variables via `SharedPreferences`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably bad practice to be handling bluetooth connections on the main thread. You should really handle the bluetooth connection/maintenance through a Service/background thread. Your activities can then talk to the service via a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and Handles.

Comment: So you mean, I don't need to bring anything over to my Input Text Page activity?

Do you mind explaining a bit more or give me a link to some examples?

Comment: Absolutely. What you want to do is create a service that handles your bluetooth connection and maintains the state of this connection (on a background thread). The service can then broadcast messages to which your relevant activities can receive from. I suggest taking  a look at [BlueTerm](http://pymasde.es/blueterm/) -- it's an open source bluetooth terminal emulator which happens to use a bluetooth service as I have described. I won't lie, it may seem daunting at first; however, it really works well.

Comment: So basically what I have on my bluetooth activity, goes to that Class which extends Service? Do I need to have a class that extends Thread or that Service class works like a Thread already? So I just dump my whole bluetooth.class into a new class that extends Service? 

I've read the BlueTerm, I'm still a bit unsure about it though.

Comment: Basically, yes. Although, I can tell you from experience that it won't be as simple as copying your code to a service. IMO, BlueTooth in Android is no trivial task to implement. I highly recommend even starting out with BlueTerm's code base (at least for the BlueTooth Service) and modifying it to fit your needs. You should also look into the BroadcastReceiver pattern to talk between your activity and the BT service, as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Alright. I'll have a look more in depth and see if I can figure something out though. Thanks